# VB.Net: Design a Class

Tags: vb.net, class, methods

I am trying to design a simple class that will contain the following code:

```
Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\1.pdf"
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
myProcess.Start()
```

I then want to use the Click event of a button to run the code. Do I have to create a method in the new class that contains the code and then call the method in the Click event of the button?

Comment: This is one of those things you could *try for yourself* and find out faster than posting a question and waiting for an answer

Comment: @Plutonix -- Agreed.  I deleted my answer.

Comment: The short answer to your question is "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what the purpose of the class is. If you want your code to be a method in the class, just make it a method.

```
Public Class TheClass
Public Sub TheMethod
    Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\1.pdf"
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    myProcess.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

To call the method in your button's click event handler, just create an instance of the class and call the method.

```
Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim theInstance As New TheClass 
    theInstance.TheMethod 
End Sub
```

If you don't have a need to create an instance of the class, you can make the method Shared: `Public Shared Sub TheMethod` and call it using the class name instead of the name of the instance: `TheClass.TheMethod`.

Comment: I created the “TheMethod” class in Form1.vb without any errors. I get a “'TheClass' is not defined.” error in the Click event of a button.

Here’s the code:
Private Sub cmdOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOK.Click
        Dim theInstance As New TheClass
        theInstance.TheMethod()

Comment: I eliminated the error by using a separate class file. Thank you.